# JavaScript: Link a input range behavior to another element

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm work on a project that involves an `<input type="range">` controlling a `<span>` inside a `<div>` in order that the `left` value of the `<span>` matches the movement of the thumb in the `<input>` proportionally. That is, when thumb reaches the end of the `<input>`, the `<span>` has to reach the end of the `<div>` and when thumb is moved to the beginning so does `<span>`. I tried a bunch of things but nothing works the way I want. I'm pretty sure there is a smart and elegant math solution, but I'm not good at it... can you guys help me?

P.S: If possible, I would like something in plain JavaScript.

[**Example in codepen**](http://codepen.io/joaosaragossa/pen/yOQKqW)

Comment: Please include your ("[mcve]") code in your question, otherwise it's meaningless if, or when, the linked codepen dies, falls over, gets reorganised or deleted, this question becomes worthless, or nonsensical.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript / jQuery - map a range of numbers to another range of numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756313/javascript-jquery-map-a-range-of-numbers-to-another-range-of-numbers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generalizing Fausto's answer,

```js
var range = document.getElementById('range'),
    fake = document.getElementById('fake-range'),
    parent = fake.parentElement;
function renderFake() {
  var available = parent.clientWidth - fake.offsetWidth,
      ratio = (range.value - range.min) / (range.max - range.min);
  fake.style.left = ratio * available + 'px';
}
range.addEventListener('input', renderFake);
window.addEventListener('resize', renderFake);
```

```css
.wrap {
  background-color: #99c;
  height: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
#fake-range {
  background-color: #000;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<input id="range" type="range" min="0" max="196" value="0">
<div class="wrap">
  <span id="fake-range"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: That's nicer yeah.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using simple JS... http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GZwxzx

```
<input id="range" onchange="updateFakeRange(this.value);" type="range" min="0" max="196" value="0">

<div class="wrap">
  <span id="fake-range"></span>
</div>
```

Notice the `onchange="updateFakeRange(this.value);"` on the input.

```
var inputRange = document.getElementById("range");
var fakeRange = document.getElementById("fake-range");
function updateFakeRange(value) {
  value = value * 100 / 196;
  fakeRange.style.left = value + "%";
}
```

I did this for fun, but take into account that this was a code request and not a real question.