# Mapping array of integers to an array of integres

Tags: javascript

I have a slider that has the following raw snap points:

```
[-100, -200, -300, -400, -500, -600]
```

And I would like to convert the sliding value to match the following snap points:

```
[0, 5, 10, 25, 50, 100]
```

- A raw value in `[-100, -200)` should be mapped to a value in `[0, 5)`
- A raw value in `[-200, -300)` should be mapped to a value in `[5, 10)`
- A raw value in `[-300, -400)` should be mapped to a value in `[10, 25)`

And so on ..

How can I achieve that?

**Edit: added my attempt (different raw values though)**

```
// sliderValue is an integer obtained from the slider

const base = -70
const offset = -80

const limits = [
  base + offset * 0, // -70
  base + offset * 1, // -150
  base + offset * 2, // -230
  base + offset * 3, // -310
  base + offset * 4, // -390
  base + offset * 5, // -470
]

const points = [0, 5, 10, 25, 50, 100]

// I can't even begin to make sense of this
// don't know I came up with it, but it works ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
if (sliderValue <= limits[4]) {
  percentage = scaleValue(sliderValue, limits[4], limits[5], 50, 100)
} else if (sliderValue <= limits[3]) {
  percentage = scaleValue(sliderValue, limits[3], limits[4], 25, 50)
} else if (sliderValue <= limits[2]) {
  percentage = scaleValue(sliderValue, limits[2], limits[3], 10, 25)
} else if (sliderValue <= limits[1]) {
  percentage = scaleValue(sliderValue, limits[1], limits[2], 5, 10)
} else if (sliderValue <= limits[0]) {
  percentage = scaleValue(sliderValue, limits[0], limits[1], 0, 5)
}

console.log(percentage)

// ..

function scaleValue(num, in_min, in_max, out_min, out_max) {
  return ((num - in_min) * (out_max - out_min)) / (in_max - in_min) + out_min
}
```

Comment: Have you tried any algorithm yet? If yes, can you share it?

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: I don't understand the relation between the numbers? How is -400, 25?

Comment: How would you do it with pencil and paper?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript / jQuery - map a range of numbers to another range of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756313/javascript-jquery-map-a-range-of-numbers-to-another-range-of-numbers)

Comment: it looks like d3 scale but smallest in domain is highest in range. are you looking for something like [this](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/lib/blob/master/src/index.js#L430-L465)?

Comment: @sp00m I updated the question with my attempt

Comment: @vlaz I did reach a solution, see updated question, but it's very confusing

Comment: @zfrischa a value in a certain range is being mapped to a value in another range, the relation is not linear

Answer (score 0):

You could take a function with a look up for the section. Then build the new value, based on the four values as a linear function.

```js
function getValue(x) {
    var a = [-100, -200, -300, -400, -500, -600],
        b = [0, 5, 10, 25, 50, 100],
        i = a.findIndex((v, i, a) => v >= x && x >= a[i + 1]);

    return [x, (x -a[i])* (b[i + 1] - b[i]) / (a[i + 1] - a[i]) +b[i]].join(' ');
}

console.log([-100, -150, -200, -250, -300, -350, -400, -450, -500, -550, -600].map(getValue));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple linear equation: add 100, divide by 20, then negate.

**UPDATE**: Due to early-morning eye bleariness, I misread the question. (Sorry!) The general method for mapping linear relations to each other is to figure out the offset of the two sets and the scale factor.

I can't find a smooth relationship between the example points you gave, so I'm not sure how to find a single equation that would neatly and continuously map the points to each other. It looks like your solution (you said it works) might be the best: figure out which range each value maps to, and scale correspondingly.

Comment: prob divide by -20

Comment: @Pointy let's meet in the middle and divide by `0`

Comment: (-580 + 100) / 20 = -24, and -24 not in [50, 100).

Comment: how about the last one ? -600+100 = 500 | 500/20 =??, it's not 100

Comment: Values in the question are arbitrary

Comment: Sorry, early in the morning for me guys. Negate result. (See updated.)

Comment: The relation is not linear

Comment: @user5470921 Oh... I missed that last range requirement. *facepalm Sorry

Comment: The first array is linear, the other `[0, 5, 10, 25, 50, 100]` is not, but please do share your idea, any help is appreciated

Comment: Is there a way for you to modify the raw snap-point values on your slider so the relation *is* linear? That will make the equation significantly simpler. Otherwise, what significance to the values `[0, 5, 10, 25, 50, 100]` have? (Just trying to figure out if there'd be an appropriate approximation.)

Comment: @AshtonWiersdorf perhaps the numbers can be changed, perhaps not. All in all, I don't think it matters in this case - it should be solveable, although you have to take each bucket and scale it onto the mapping range. E.g. -430 would fall into the `[-400, -500)` bucket, the matching one is `[25, 50)`. Now just scale the first 100 points range to a 25 points one and project the value onto it. The total range's linearity (or lack thereof) is irrelevant in this case. OP is looking for a more elegant way to do the this effect, though.

Answer (score -1):

You can just map the values:

```js
var mapping = {
  "-100": 0,
  "-200": 5,
  "-300": 10,
  "-400": 25,
  "-500": 50,
  "-600": 100
}

function map_values(array){
  return [mapping[array[0]], mapping[array[1]]];
}

var input = [-200,-300];

console.log(map_values(input));
```

Comment: This only handles the boundaries of the ranges, not the ranges themselves.

Comment: @AshtonWiersdorf That was not part of the question.

Comment: It is, actually. He's asking about how to map half-open intervals onto each other. (That's what the notation `[a,b)` means: a value greater than or equal to `a`, but less than `b`.) (Good thought though!) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)#Notations_for_intervals