# How to style input range slider with before and after to achieve my requirement

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a requirement of making something like below

[image]

**Note:**: above image is having V kind of icon, that is what I'm trying.

Actually I'm using `input[type="range"]`.

Below styles are not working:

```
input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 30%;
}
```

Here is what I have tried:

```js
const range = document.getElementById("range");

// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756313/javascript-jquery-map-a-range-of-numbers-to-another-range-of-numbers
const scale = (num, in_min, in_max, out_min, out_max) => {
  return ((num - in_min) * (out_max - out_min)) / (in_max - in_min) + out_min;
};

range.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
  const value = +e.target.value;
  const label = e.target.nextElementSibling;
  const rangeWidth = getComputedStyle(e.target).getPropertyValue("width");
  const labelWidth = getComputedStyle(label).getPropertyValue("width");
  // remove px
  const numWidth = +rangeWidth.substring(0, rangeWidth.length - 2);
  const numLabelWidth = +labelWidth.substring(0, labelWidth.length - 2);
  const max = +e.target.max;
  const min = +e.target.min;
  const left =
    value * (numWidth / max) -
    numLabelWidth / 2 +
    scale(value, min, max, 10, -10);
  label.style.left = `${left}px`;
  label.innerHTML = value;
});
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato&display=swap");

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, #f5f7fa 0%, #c3cfe2 100%);
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}

h2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
}

.range-container {
  position: relative;
}

input[type="range"] {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 18px 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

input[type="range"]:focus,input[type="range"]:active {
  outline: none;
  cursor: grabbing !important;
}

input[type="range"] + label {
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: -25px;
  left: 110px;
  width: 80px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

/* Chrome & Safari */
input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  height: 120px;
  width: 2px;
  background: red;
  cursor: grab;
}


input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 30%;
}
```

```html
<h2>Custom Range Slider</h2>
    <div class="range-container">
      <input type="range" name="range" step="10" id="range" min="0" max="100" data-red="yellow"/>
      <label for="range">50</label>
    </div>
```

What can I try next?

Answer (score 1):

Add the following css to your code, here I've used before pseudo selector to place the triangle right below own slider

```
input[type="range"]+label::before {
    content: "";
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 50% 100%, 100% 0); // check https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/ to generate shapes
    width: 21px;
    height: 20px;
    background: white;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 29px;
    left: -0.5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 2px;
    border-top-left-radius: 2px;
}
```

Update the following css selector

```
input[type="range"]+label {
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: -35px;
    left: 140px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

Change the following JS line. Make 10, -10 to 0,0

```
  const left =
    value * (numWidth / max) -
    numLabelWidth / 2 +
    scale(value, min, max, 0, 0);
```

Below is a working snippet

```js
const range = document.getElementById("range");

// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756313/javascript-jquery-map-a-range-of-numbers-to-another-range-of-numbers
const scale = (num, in_min, in_max, out_min, out_max) => {
  return ((num - in_min) * (out_max - out_min)) / (in_max - in_min) + out_min;
};

range.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
  const value = +e.target.value;
  const label = e.target.nextElementSibling;
  const rangeWidth = getComputedStyle(e.target).getPropertyValue("width");
  const labelWidth = getComputedStyle(label).getPropertyValue("width");
  // remove px
  const numWidth = +rangeWidth.substring(0, rangeWidth.length - 2);
  const numLabelWidth = +labelWidth.substring(0, labelWidth.length - 2);
  const max = +e.target.max;
  const min = +e.target.min;
  const left =
    value * (numWidth / max) -
    numLabelWidth / 2 +
    scale(value, min, max, 0, 0);
  label.style.left = `${left}px`;
  label.innerHTML = value;
});
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato&display=swap");

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, #f5f7fa 0%, #c3cfe2 100%);
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}

h2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
}

.range-container {
  position: relative;
}

input[type="range"] {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 18px 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

input[type="range"]:focus,input[type="range"]:active {
  outline: none;
  cursor: grabbing !important;
}

input[type="range"] + label {
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: -35px;
  left: 140px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
  font-size: 10px
}

input[type="range"] + label::before {
content: "";
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 50% 100%, 100% 0);
    width: 21px;
    height: 20px;
    background: white;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 29px;
    left: -0.5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 2px;
    border-top-left-radius: 2px;
}

/* Chrome & Safari */
input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  height: 120px;
  width: 2px;
  background: red;
  cursor: grab;
}


input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 30%;
}
```

```html
<h2>Custom Range Slider</h2>
    <div class="range-container">
      <input type="range" name="range" step="10" id="range" min="0" max="100" data-red="yellow"/>
      <label for="range">50</label>
    </div>
```

Comment: design wise it is correct solution but working wise it is not correct solution with handle i,e white color in your case over top of red vertical we should be able to move the slider with it.